# Lenovo S10 very laggy on startup

Tags: performance, lenovo-laptop, netbook, lag, microsoft-publisher

I have a Lenovo S10 netbook, and recently the computer is slow and laggy. Applications take a long time to start, mouse and keyboard input is choppy, etc. It has been dropped a few times, and has been blue-screening lately. It's currently running Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit with 1 GB ram.

I ran Resource Monitor, but there was no odd disk or CPU activity, and the memory was hovering at about 700 MB (just Windows Live Messenger, and Firefox with no tabs open). If it helps, just before it started being laggy, Publisher was malfunctioning. Is there anything I can do to make it less laggy, at least until I can investigate getting a replacement?

**Update:** It seems that when I open Microsoft Publisher (from office 2007), the computer becomes laggy, persisting after closing the program and even after restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its been dropped several times and you're getting blue screens and lag, you might start with testing the hard drive. 
Other questions to address:
What are the hex codes it gives you when it blue screens? - this could give you a more specific reason that there are problems, at least differentiating between hardware or software issues.
Does it still lag in safe mode? - this could indicate if it is just software loading in normal mode that is causing the lag and blue screens.

Comment: I'll try those things ASAP!

Comment: OK, its not choppy when running in Safe Mode. Does that mean that it's something that was installed recently?

Comment: It could indicate that, it could also indicate some sort of malware/viral infection as well.

Comment: OK, i have more information. It seems that when i open Microsoft Publisher (from office 2007), the computer becomes laggy, persisting after closing the program and even after restarts.

Comment: If you have not yet updated Office 2007 to SP2, you can here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=B444BF18-79EA-46C6-8A81-9DB49B4AB6E5&displaylang=en - But honestly, you might just need something to manage your computer's RAM better, or you might need to get more RAM. Publisher can be heavy on memory, and 1 GB to share between windows and publisher is not much.